# How can I use bulk insert in the case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

how can I use bulk insert from array in Rails, like below:

```
name_list = [{"id" => 1,"name" => "bob"},{"id" => 2,"name" => "ted"}]

Namelist.import name_list
```

I can`t insert values of above array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in **single insert query** using [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem.

```
name_list = [{"id" => 1,"name" => "bob"},{"id" => 2,"name" => "ted"}]
namelist_objects = []
name_list.each do |n| 
  namelist_objects << Namelist.new(n)
end
Namelist.import(namelist_objects)
```

The above answers of others will work fine but `name_list.size` number of insert queries will run which is not feasible when the array is big.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the array of hash to [`create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class)

```
Namelist.create([{id: 1, name: "bob"}, {id: 2, name: "ted"}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want, but maybe it will help you. I think you want create Namelist for both name_lists, isn't ?

```
name_list = [{"id" => 1,"name" => "bob"},{"id" => 2,"name" => "ted"}]
name_list.map{|k| Namelist.create(k) }
```